# Got error `undefined reference to `getauxval’` during Rust cross-compile to aarch64 on x86_64

Tags: rust, cross-compiling, arm64, openwrt, toolchain

I am trying to build Rust application for two OpenWRT routers. One is on ramips (mipsel) platform and another is on rockchip (aarch64) platform.

I completed the cross-compilation for mipsel very well, but blocked for aarch64 with error message `undefined reference to 'getauxval'`. Please see below for details.

```
(...)
-linux-musl/lib/self-contained" "-o" "/tmp/hello-reqwest/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/debug/deps/hello_reqwest-4e5be7f0a2aebac1" "-Wl,--gc-sections" "-static" "-no-pie" "-Wl,-zrelro,-znow" "-nodefaultlibs" "/home/janvier/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtend.o" "/home/janvier/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/self-contained/crtn.o"
  = note: /home/janvier/toolchain/toolchain-aarch64_generic_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/../lib/gcc/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl/11.2.0/../../../../aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl/bin/ld: /home/janvier/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/aarch64-unknown-linux-musl/lib/libcompiler_builtins-0a28d23d76fcec1d.rlib(cpu_model.o): in function `init_have_lse_atomics':
          /cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/compiler_builtins-0.1.85/./lib/builtins/cpu_model.c:829: undefined reference to `getauxval'
          collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
          
  = note: some `extern` functions couldn't be found; some native libraries may need to be installed or have their path specified
  = note: use the `-l` flag to specify native libraries to link
  = note: use the `cargo:rustc-link-lib` directive to specify the native libraries to link with Cargo (see https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#cargorustc-link-libkindname)

error: could not compile `hello-reqwest` due to previous error
```

*main.rs*

```
use std::error::Error;
use reqwest::Client;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let client = Client::new();
    let response = client.get("https://www.example.com").send().await?;
    let body = response.text().await?;
    println!("Body:\n{}", body);
    Ok(())
}
```

*Cargo.toml*

```
[package]
name = "hello-reqwest"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
reqwest = "0.11.16"
tokio = { version = "1.27.0", features = ["full"] }
openssl = { version = "0.10.50", features = ["vendored"] }
```

and *~/.cargo/config.toml*

```
[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "/home/janvier/openwrt-sdk-22.03.2/rockchip/staging_dir/toolchain-aarch64_generic_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc"

[target.mipsel-unknown-linux-musl]
linker = "/home/janvier/openwrt-sdk-22.03.2/ramips/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_24kc_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/mipsel-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc"
```

The code and configuration works well for cross-compiling to mipsel, but failed to aarch64.

Is anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Your C toolchain is broken. The libgcc that your compiler is using was built for `linux-gnu` target, but you're trying to compile for `linux-musl`.

Comment: But I have specified `toolchain-aarch64_generic_gcc-11.2.0_musl/bin/aarch64-openwrt-linux-musl-gcc` as linker in `[target.aarch64-unknown-linux-musl]` section. This should be musl but not the gnu one.

Comment: Yes, you're compiling for `linux-musl`, and your libc is indeed musl and not glibc, which is what's causing the error, because libgcc was built against glibc. I don't know where this libgcc is coming from or why your toolchain is using that one. Try adding `-v` to the flags passed to gcc, that may reveal more.

Comment: After inspecting the error message, I noticed the problem was on a file named `libcompiler_builtins-0a28d23d76fcec1d.rlib`, which came with `rustup target add`. Actually they are part of LLVM's compiler-rt.

Comment: @JanvierP. did you end up solving this issue? I'm experiencing the same one

Comment: @cor not yet. I have submitted a bug on [github](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/3324) which is still open.